# Вставки на си в приложении си шарп

Tags: c#

Как можно такое сделать, например для увеличения быстродействия программы ?

Comment: крайне сомневаюсь в необходимости такого шага. Скорее всего, вам нужно обратить внимание на собственно алгоритм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте про [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx).

А вообще, может, лучше пересмотреть алгоритм? Переходом на C вы выиграете не так уж много.

Comment: ... а, скорее, даже проиграете.

Comment: @VladD а как можно их вообще совместить? Архитектуры-то разные -- .net и какой-то конкретный процессор (x86, arm, и т.д.)

Comment: @alexlz: P/Invoke может. В .NET есть Interop-layer: часть, занимающаяся маршаллированием данных между нативными структурами и собственно .NET. Нативная часть при этом должна соответствовать архитектуре, то есть код становится сразу плохо переносимым. (Ну или для каждой архитектуры нужна своя нативная часть.) При вызове функции через P/Invoke аргументы приводятся к нативному виду, отдаются нативной функции, получается результат, из него «собирается» .NET-объект, и возвращается назад. Это всё транспарентно для пользователя.

Comment: > Это всё транспарентно для пользователя.

Oh u...

Comment: читал статью, кажется о hadoop (не уверен точно). Помню, что там все на java и им нужно было вычислять crc файлов. Так вот, замена одной небольшой функции на нативную (той, которая по имени файла пересчитывает crc), дала общий прирост в 4 раза. Так что в некоторых случаях переписывание всего одной функции правильно может сильно повлиять на общую картину.

Comment: > Так что в некоторых случаях переписывание всего одной функции правильно может сильно повлиять на общую картину.

Это случаи, когда нужно что-то считать. Не уверен насчет Java, но CLR не использует для ускорения вычислений MMX\SSE.